# Calculator on python won't show any result ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, calculator

```
print("Calculadora 2")
task = input("Choose a task (+, -, *, /): ")
n1 = input("Number 1: ")
n2 = input("Number 2: ")

print(float(n1 + task + n2))
```

When I try to run this code it says: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2+3'
How can I make it not a string and a number(float).

Comment: Of course? You cannot convert ```+,/,-,*``` to float

Comment: Try `print(eval(n1 + task + n2))`

Comment: search for eval and python

Comment: don't use eval if you're not going to sanitise the users inputs .... - `"__import__('os').remove('important file')"`

Answer (score 1):

Here, `eval` can be very useful. However, use it cautiously:

```
print("Calculadora 2")
task = input("Choose a task (+, -, *, /): ")
n1 = input("Number 1: ")
n2 = input("Number 2: ")

print(eval(n1+task+n2))
```

Comment: thanks, but why the "use it cautiously", I am kinda curious now

Comment: [Why is using ```eval``` dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice). Check it out @Eyyt4